# how to add another include path in make

Tags: makefile

i want to use iostream or stdlib.h in my linux kernel driver and i have this MakeFile

```
ifeq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

.PHONY: build clean

build:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR)  M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c
else

$(info Building with KERNELRELEASE = ${KERNELRELEASE})
obj-m :=    mydev.o

endif
```

when i use #include  in my driver code, make returns this

```
mydev.c:10:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
```

what should i add to my makefile?

Answer (score 0):

iostream is a C++ header. The Kernel is written in C

Comment: what about stdio.h?
i replaced iostream with stdio.h and had a same problem.

Comment: You can't use anything from libc, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386852/can-stdio-be-used-while-coding-for-a-kernel